# Alpine Expression Error: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm encountering this error after moving my Tile class to `Tile.js` and moving the game data from `app.js` to `game.js`. When all the JS is in the same file everything works fine, but once I break it up into different files I get the error in the title. There's a lot of posts with similar questions, but almost everyone I looked at was broken due to a syntax error or something simple. I don't think that is the case here.

Error:

```
Alpine Expression Error: board is not defined

Expression: "board"

HTMLTemplateElement{attributes: {…}, innerHTML: "\n <div class=\"row\">\n <template x-for=\"tile in row\">\n <div class=\"tile\" x-text=\"tile.letter\"><…", nodeType: 1, tagName: "template"}
```

[Reproduction on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-njsmab?file=index.html,app.js,game.js,styles.scss,Tile.js)

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/" target="_blank" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.scss" />
    <script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
    <script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="game" x-data="game" @keyup.window="onKeyPress($event.key)">
      <template x-for="row in board">
        <div class="row">
          <template x-for="tile in row">
            <div class="tile" x-text="tile.letter"></div>
          </template>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
// app.js
import game from './game';

document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('game', () => game);
});
```

```
// game.js
import Tile from './Tile';

export default {
  guessesAllowed: 5,
  wordLength: 5,
  currentRowIndex: 0,

  init() {
    this.board = Array.from({ length: this.guessesAllowed }, () => {
      return Array.from({ length: this.wordLength }, () => new Tile());
    });
  },

  onKeyPress(key) {
    if (/^[A-z]$/.test(key)) {
      this.fillTile(key);
    }
  },

  fillTile(key) {
    for (let tile of this.currentRow()) {
      if (!tile.letter) {
        tile.fill(key);
        break;
      }
    }

    if (this.currentTileIndex === this.wordLength - 1) {
      this.currentRowIndex++;
      this.currentTileIndex = 0;
    } else {
      this.currentTileIndex++;
    }
  },

  currentRow() {
    return this.board[this.currentRowIndex];
  },
};
```

```
// Tile.js
export default class Tile {
  letter = '';
  status = ''; // 'correct', 'incorrect', 'empty'
  
  fill(key) {
      this.letter = key.toUpperCase();
      this.status = 'filled';
  }
  
  empty() {
      this.letter = '';
      this.status = 'empty';
  }
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the error, and where/when does it happen?

Comment: Take a look at the Stackblitz project I linked. The error is `Alpine Expression Error: board is not defined Expression: "board"`

Comment: Code, errors, and debugging information should be posted **here** in the question, in general. External links can break.

Comment: What calls `init()`? Until that's called, the object referred to in your `x-data` attribute won't have a "board" property. (I know almost nothing about Alpine however.)

Comment: As an experiment, you could change the `.data()` call to `Alpine.data('game', () => (game.init(), game))`

Comment: That didn't change anything unfortunately. This usage of init comes from Jeffrey Way's laracast video on building a wordle clone. I don't see how he used it in the Alpine docs https://alpinejs.dev/directives/init#auto-evaluate-init-method it seems like it's similar to Vue's `created()` or `mounted()` hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging I found that your `alpine:init` event never got triggered. And even though you have `defer` on your Alpine CDN, I suppose it was still loaded in before your app script.

```html
<script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
```

By loading your `app.js` first you ensure the event listener is set before Alpine is loaded, and thus your `Alpine.data` is actually executed.